# Why doesn't the "conda" command find the "updatable" packages?

Tags: python, anaconda

When I run `conda update --all` or `conda update --update-all` it says:

`# All requested packages already installed.`

However, the Anaconda Navigator shows 54 packages that are "Updatable".

Why such a difference and how can the command line option be fixed?

**UPDATE:** When I mark the "updatable" packages for the update in Anaconda Navigator and click "Apply", it starts to work and then shows the same message as the "conda" command:

`# All requested packages already installed.`

Then it shows the original number of the "updatable" packages.

So it's quite clear that this is not just the command problem and that the version dependency resolution does not work properly.

As a WORKAROUND, I updated the packages in small batches (5-10) via UI - the Anaconda Navigator was not falsely reporting that all the packages were up to date.

Comment: Msybe those packages are in another environment? Just a guess.

Comment: No, I have only one environment. But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Same issue, not even a single updateable package ist updated. it tells me: "already installed"